# Query sql para cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp-3

Como faço a query abaixo no cakephp?

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM tramitacaos
    INNER JOIN protocolos ON tramitacaos.protocolo_id = protocolos.id
    WHERE (
    protocolo_id, data_origem
    )
    IN (
    SELECT protocolo_id, MAX( data_origem ) 
    FROM tramitacaos
    WHERE unidade_origem_id =462
    GROUP BY protocolo_id
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar essa `query` usando o [`ConnectionManager`](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#running-select-statements)

```
use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;

$connection = ConnectionManager::get('default');
$results = $connection->execute(
    'SELECT 
        * 
    FROM tramitacaos
    INNER JOIN protocolos 
        ON tramitacaos.protocolo_id = protocolos.id
    WHERE 
        (protocolo_id, data_origem) IN 
        (
            SELECT 
                protocolo_id, 
                MAX( data_origem ) 
            FROM 
                tramitacaos
            WHERE 
                unidade_origem_id = :unidadeOrigemId
            GROUP BY protocolo_id
        )',
        ['unidadeOrigemId' => 462]
    )->fetchAll('assoc');
```